# Why is USBview display "Is Port Debug Capable" as "no" on my PC?

Tags: debugging, windows-kernel

I'm trying to setup Windows kernel debugging via USB 3.0 transport. [This MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439372(v=vs.85).aspx) says I have to check my PC with USBview.exe first, and it requires  "Is Port Debug Capable" to say yes. However, on my Windows 10 x64 system on Acer R7 laptop(Intel Ivy Bridge Core i5 3337U), "Is Port Debug Capable" says **no** for each USB 3.0 port. Why is it so?

[image: usbview - Is Port Debug Capable.png]

Comment: My experience is that not all USB ports have debug capabilities (actually, most of them do not). On my old notebook, one port actually had debug capabilities, however, it was just an internal one (in had no external connector). Consider debugging over other means (Ethernet, firewire if possible, VirtualKD "extension" for VMWare if you need to debug virtual machines).

Comment: Thanks. I've tried Ethernet transport and VirtualKD transport, and they both work well. But the real-world situation is, more and more Ultrabooks, Tablets don't equip an Ethernet port, so USB 3.0 seems to become the last resort.

Comment: @JimmChen have you asked Acer? There may be some hidden bios setting to enable USB debugging.